# Grails unit testing service with spock mocking functionality

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.0, spock

Presently trying to test a Grails **service** (*Experience with Geb functional testing*)

Trying to **mock the necessary required data** that the service will need (e.g. User,etc.) ... no matter how I seem to declare/initialize the domains of interest they **all appear as NULL in all my tests methods**

I'm trying to set this required information once, so it can be reused through the test methods.

```
@TestFor(ReminderService)
@Mock([Reminder, User, Subscriptions, Organisation, UserOrganisation, OrganisationRole, Ref, Role, Title])
class ReminderServiceTests extends Specification {

@Shared user, org, userOrg, roleUser, sub, orgRole, ti, refVals, reminder
def mailService


def setup() {
    def refSubStatus  = new Ref(value: 'Current').save()
    def refSubPublic  = new Ref(value: 'No').save()
    def refSubType    = new Ref(value: 'Subscription Taken').save()
    def refRemUnit    = new Ref(value: 'Month').save()
    def refOrgRole    = new Ref(value: 'Subscriber').save()
    def refRemMethod  = new Ref(value: 'email').save()
    def refRemTrigger = new Ref(value: 'Subscription Manual Renewal Date').save()
    reminder          = new Reminder(user: user,  active: true, amount: 1, unit:refRemUnit, reminderMethod:refRemMethod, trigger: refRemTrigger, lastRan:null).save()
    refVals     = [refSubStatus,refSubPublic, refSubType, refRemUnit, refOrgRole, refRemMethod, refRemTrigger]
    roleUser          = new Role(authority: 'BASIC_USER', roleType:'global').save()

    ti                = new Title(title: "A random title....", impId: UUID.randomUUID().toString()).save()
    sub               = new Subscription(name:"A random subscription name",
                                         status:refSubStatus,
                                         identifier:UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                                         impId:UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                                         startDate:new LocalDate().minusYears(1).toDate(),
                                         endDate: new LocalDate().plusMonths(1).toDate(),
                                         isPublic: refSubPublic,
                                         type: refSubType,
                                         renewal: new LocalDate().minusMonths(3).toDate()).save()
    org               = new Organisation(name: "new org", impId: UUID.randomUUID().toString()).save()
    orgRole           = new OrganisationRole(sub: sub, roleType: refOrgRole, org: org).save()
    user              = new User(username: 'j_doe', firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", email: 'example@googlemail.com', defaultDash: org).save()
    userOrg           = new UserOrganisation(org: org, user: user, formalRole: roleUser, status: 1).save()
    mailService       = new MailService()
//        mockDomain(Ref, refdataValues)
//        mockDomain(Title, ti)
//        mockDomain(OrganisationRole, orgRole)
//        mockDomain(Organisation, org)
//        mockDomain(User, user)
//        mockDomain(UserOrganisation, userOrg)
//        mockDomain(Reminder, reminder)
}


def "Getting subscriptions for a user"() {
    when:
    def subscriptions = service.getAuthorisedSubsciptionsByUser(user)

    then:
    subscriptions != null
    subscriptions.size() > 0
}
```

Everything is null, I've tried using mockDomain (See commented out section in `setup()`, including using `setupSpec()` something is not quite right)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using @Shared? AS I see it now, you don't need it. Your references are shared throughout the lifecycle of the Spec, but you put your init code in setup, which is called before each spec. That does not seem right. @Shared variables are internally stored in a different instance than the normal variables, so there may be some kind of mixup. Also, you might try to use setupSpec() instead of setup() for @Shared variables.

Comment: `Compilation error compiling [unit] tests: startup failed: Only @Shared and static fields may be accessed from here`   ... Am I mixing two different testing styles, I changed it to use `setupSpec()`? If I leave it as `setup()` without shared it runs, but still the issue as in OP...Such a confusing topic, thanks for the assistance

Comment: If you are using your values in setupSpec, or in where blocks, then you will have to use @Shared values. However I have found out that it often is not worth the headache, especially when using Domain classes in grails. I just create a separate fixture for each spec, and refactor the fixture code. It's almost as DRY, though not as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
@TestFor(SomeService)
@Mock([DomainClass])
class SomeServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def "test someMethod"() {
        given:
            def x = new DomainClass(attr1: 'a', attr2: 'b').save(flush: true)
        when:
            def result = service.someMethod() // returns that saved Domain instance
        then:
            result instanceof DomainClass
            result.attr1 == 'a'
            result.attr2 == 'b'
    }
}
```

.save() has proven insufficient in my unit tests, while .save(flush: true) produces the desired results.